# getting row and column from mouse click event

Tags: python, events, mouseevent

I have code to display rows and columns.

I wanted to get the row and column in shell,if I click with my mouse over the specified location consisting like R0/C0 in the GUI

My coding:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk(  )
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(4):
        Tkinter.Label(root, text='R%s/C%s'%(r,c),
            borderwidth=1 ).grid(row=r,column=c)
root.mainloop(  )
```

[image]

If i click my mouse over R2/C2 in the GUI,then it should display the output in shell as `R2/C2`

Please help me on how to attain this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()

def handle_click(text):
    print text

for r in range(3):
    for c in range(6):
        text = 'R%s/C%s'%(r,c)
        label = Tkinter.Label(root, text=text, borderwidth=1 )
        label.grid(row=r,column=c)
        label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, text=text:handle_click(text))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the best answer!thought it would be difficult!made easy!thanks!